# Apply ZoneId to Date object in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, timezone-offset

I have the following date object `Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017`. This obviously is in GMT, however, I'd like to consider it to be in a different timezone.

As an example, I'd like to consider the above date in the following timezone `US/Mountain` and I'd like to then convert it to UTC, resulting in `Wed Nov 01 07:00:00 UTC`.

I've tried to find a way to change the timezone of a date, while preserving the time, but failed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use java.util.Date or java.time.LocalDate ?

Comment: I'm using java.util.Date

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea, then stop doing that. Sorry, I couldn’t resist. Seriously, the modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with, I recommend changing.

Comment: BTW, a `java.util.Date` object isn’t in GMT. It has not got a time zone nor offset in it, it’s just a point on the timeline. It’s just its `toString` method that fools you (and many others) into believing there’s a zone in there.

Comment: And BTW, the java-time tag refers to the `java.time` API, so if you didn’t intend this, the usage of the tag is incorrect. You may want to add the java.util.date tag instead. I still recommend you rather start using `java.time`, though.

Comment: @OleV.V. Correction: The [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class is indeed documented as being intended to represent a time in UTC (albeit ignoring leap seconds), which in practical terms for business-oriented apps is the same as GMT.  *“…the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC),…”*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from you comment that you have got a `java.util.Date` instance. It prints as (for example) `Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017`. This is what its `toString` method produces. The `Date` doesn’t have a time zone in it. Usually `Date.toString()` grabs the JVM’s time zone setting and renders the date in this time zone. So it appears you are running GMT time zone? You can read more in [this popular blog entry: All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

If you can, avoid having a `Date`. [The modern Java date and time API known as `java.time` or JSR-310](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with, both in general and not least for time zone magic like yours. Then use [assylias’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570275/5772882).

For this answer I am assuming that you got a `Date` from some legacy API that you cannot change (or cannot afford to change just now). I still recommend the modern API for the change you desire. The output from the following snippet I give as comments in the code.

```
    System.out.println(oldFashionedDateObject); // Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017
    // first thing, convert the Date to an instance of a modern class, Instant
    Instant pointInTime = oldFashionedDateObject.toInstant();
    // convert to same hour and minute in US/Mountain and then back into UTC
    ZonedDateTime convertedDateTime = pointInTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId.of("US/Mountain"))
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(convertedDateTime); // 2017-11-01T06:00Z

    // only assuming you absolutely and indispensably need an old-fashioned Date object back
    oldFashionedDateObject = Date.from(convertedDateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldFashionedDateObject); // Wed Nov 01 06:00:00 GMT 2017
```

As assylias, I got `Wed Nov 01 06:00:00`. According to [Current Local Time in Denver, Colorado, USA](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/denver) summer time (DST) ended on November 5 this year.

Answer (score 1):

With the java time API, you can:

1. Parse the string as a `ZonedDateTime`
2. Use the `zonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal` and `zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant` to convert the result

Something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu");

ZonedDateTime gmt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017", fmt);
ZonedDateTime mountain = gmt.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("US/Mountain"));
ZonedDateTime utc = mountain.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(utc.format(fmt));
```

which, by the way, outputs: `Wed Nov 01 06:00:00 Z 2017` (the DST will be in effect on November 3rd only).